# Jenkins github-organization-folder dont build on pull requests

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

is it possible to configure github-organization-folder plugin to not start build automatically on pull request? Only start pull request manualy when i want?

Comment: Interesting question, I only know how to do this based on the branch name..

Comment: @StephenKing how you do tnie basen on branch name?

Comment: _Suppress automatic SCM triggering_ in the job config.